# Page node edit content-type

Tags: 7, theming, nodes

How I can customize the node edit page? I need to use a custom template for it.
page--node--add-content-type.tpl.php works fine, but --edit--content-type.tpl.php doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it now.

```
function HOOK_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    if (isset($variables['node']->type)) {
        $nodetype = $variables['node']->type;
        $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__' . $nodetype;
    }
    if (!empty($variables['node']) && arg(2) == 'edit') {
        $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__node__' . $variables['node']->type .'__edit';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [function hook_preprocess_HOOK](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7.x).

```
function themeName_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
    if (!empty($vars['node']) && arg(2) == 'edit') {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__node__' . $vars['node']->type .'__edit';
  }
}
```

This allowed me to use: page--node--[contentType]--edit.tpl.php

Clear cache.